# newKieSession() for KieContainer and KieBase behave differently

Tags: spring-boot, drools, rule-engine

I am trying to pass 70k messages through rule engine one by one. I want to bring down the processing time for this. The newKieSession() instantiation as per below implementation takes around 0.8 seconds in each loop which is too much. Although it evaluates messages accurately.

DroolsBeanFactory

```
public KieSession getKieSession() {
    getKieRepository();
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/demo/Rule1.drl"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/demo/Rule2.drl"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/demo/Rule3.drl"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/demo/Rule4.drl"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/demo/Rule5.drl"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/example/demo/Rule6.drl"));

    KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kb.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();

    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
    return kContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

When I tried to replace newKieSession creation with KieBase's method the instantiation time is significantly lesser but it does not evaluate rules correctly... I think it stops evaluating messages correctly after 36-37 loops.

kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules-kb" packages="com.example.demo">
</kbase>
```

Implementation file

```
@Autowired
KieBase kBase

for(String message: messages) {

//KieSession kieSession = new DroolsBeanFactory.getKieSession(); // takes long time, evaluates correctly
KieSession kieSession = kBase.newKieSession(); // quick instantiation, wrong evaluation

kieSession.insert(...);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
KieSession.dispose();

}
```

Why are they behaving differently ? How can we bring down instantiation time for kiesession and also evaluate messages correctly ?

Comment: Why do you rebuild the kie file system every time to get the KieSession O__O

Comment: I expose my KieContainer as a bean. I get the KieBases I'm targetting out of the container, then get the session off of the kbase. I don't see what you're complaining about of "not evaluating rules correctly" and without more information about what you mean by that (including what your rules look like) I'm not sure we can help you. But your `getKieSession` method is amazingly inefficient so you probably shouldn't be doing it that way anyway.

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable. I'll try that and let you know. The reason for inaccuracy was the split method of String. split() works fine for KieContainer's newSession() but does not work for KieBase. Don't know why.